# How to return slice by reference?

Tags: go

The returned slice by reference is empty:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func GetItems(items *[]string) {
    list := make([]string, 0)
    list = append(list, "ok")
    items = &list
}

func main() {
    var items []string
    GetItems(&items)
    fmt.Print(len(items)) // expect 1 here, but got 0
}
```

How to return the slice from the function by reference?

Comment: Why want you pass slice by reference, just curious? Since slice is reference type itself doing double reference looks not very good idea for me.

Comment: I have some mgo (mongodb) code that use this pattern - http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Iter.All - so in order to not refactor too much I would like to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By assigning to `items`, you alter where `items` points, not the value `items` points to. To do the latter, instead of `items = &list` write `*items = list`.