# How to change pointer slice in golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to get a better understanding of go. I created a little exercise for myself: pass a pointer slice to a function and modify it.

This is what I came up with:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    var data *[]byte
    fillData(data)
    fmt.Println((*data)[0:5])
}

func fillData(data *[]byte) {
    b := []byte("hello")
    fmt.Println(b[0:5])
    fmt.Println(string(b[0:5]))
    data = (*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&b[0]))
}
```

But it gives an `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` error. I know I wouldn't use something like this in real code but I was just curious how to pass a slice and modify it without returning it.

https://play.golang.org/p/_K5ltKKKNV

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319883/how-to-return-slice-by-reference

Comment: Don't use `unsafe`. You can change what the thing a pointer is pointing at (instead of where it is pointing) by dereferencing it with `*`. `*data = b`. Of course you rarely ever need to to pass a pointer to a slice and it's usually better instead to return a slice (possible modified), ala `append`.

Comment: You also are not allocating the `data` variable so you're trying to modify what is pointed to by a nil pointer. E.g. https://play.golang.org/p/C6kiW-vbJn

Comment: That's it. I was missing the new() call. I'll go read up on that. Thanks for the help Dave! If you'll post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you try to update `data` in `fillData`, you make two errors. First, you update the pointer rather than what it's pointed to. Second, `data` is a nil pointer, so writing through that pointer will cause a nil pointer error.

Here's one possible way to write the code. `data` starts as a zero'ed slice, and gets updated inside `fillData`. This will copy the slice information (len, cap, and pointer to array) from `b` to `*data` which means that `data` will share information with `b` (importantly, including sharing the underlying array).

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var data []byte
    fillData(&data)
    fmt.Println(data, data[0:5])
}

func fillData(data *[]byte) {
    b := []byte("hello")
    *data = b[0:1]
}
```

Another way would be to have `data` being a pointer, and updating it. Then you have to pass a double pointer into `fillData`. That would look like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var data *[]byte
    fillData(&data)
    fmt.Println((*data)[0:5])
}

func fillData(data **[]byte) {
    b := []byte("hello")
    *data = &b
}
```

Finally, the best way to write this code isn't to use pointers at all, and just return the slice. Unlike C or C++, it's rarely needed to use "output" parameters to functions. That's because go allows multiple return values.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    data := getData()
    fmt.Println(data, data[0:5])
}

func getData() []byte {
    return []byte("hello")[:1]
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement pop method for queue, using slice in Golang write it like this
func (queue *Queue) pop() int {
 var res int = (*queue)[0];
 *queue = (*queue)[1:];
 return res;
}